# Batch Renaming Script

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a script that will let me batch rename jpg/png files from their origin name to 01.jpg (or 01.png) 02.jpg 03.jpg and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is freeware renaming software that you could use.

Comment: A powershell one liner `$cnt=1;gci *.png,*.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D2}{1}' -f $script:cnt++,$_.Extension} -WhatIf` if the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

An example [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) script to rename arbitrary files to a numerical sequence with leading zeros.

Make sure to use the latest version of Python 3 (i.e. [Python 3.7.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/) as of this writing). You will probably want to create the appropriate `.py` file associations during installation and add `python.exe` to your path.

Once Python is installed, you will also need the [natsort module](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) from PyPI for natural (rather than lexographical) sorting. You can install it with e.g.:

```
python -m pip install natsort
```

---

**Notes**

- Sequences always begin at zero.
- 0 is always represented with two digits or more (e.g. 00, 000, etc.).
- Zeros are only placed in front of numbers less than the maximum number of
  digits (excluding items 1-10). So ex.:

  - Items 1-10 become 00-09
  - Items 1-100 become 00-09 then 10-99
  - Items 1-101 become 000-099 then 100
  - Items 1-1001 become 0000 - 0999 then 1000
- `time` and `print` statements are completely optional (and are thus included, but commented out with `#`).

---

**Caveats**

As configured below, this script:

- Has renaming turned off by default. Set `rename=True` once you are certain it functions the way you would like it to.
- Only operates on the directory from which it was called (and never subdirectories).
- Looks for files ending in both `.jpg` and `.png`. If you don't want it to look for these files to rename, you'll need to edit portions of the script.
- Renames files as encountered. This means some images can (potentially) be renamed out of their intended order. Certain instances of this can be overcome with natural sorting (currently implemented in the script below). That said, if Windows returns e.g. `some-jpeg.jpg`, `some-png.png` when asked for the contents of the current directory, this script will rename these e.g. `00.jpg`, `01.png`, etc. As a partial fix, you can simply have e.g. only `.jpg` or only `.png`  files in the directory.
- There are undoubtedly any number of improvements that could be made to this script. =)

---

**Script**

*ex. seq_rename.py*:

```
# Rename files to a numerical sequence with leading zeros.

# We use the natsort module (available from PyPI) to provide a natural (rather
# than lexographical) sort of file names.

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

# natsort module
# https://pypi.org/project/natsort/

# --- Imports ---

import os
import os.path
import time

# Import our natural sorting module
from natsort import natsorted

# --- Variables ---

# Turn renaming on or off. Values are "True" or "False".
rename = False

# "." is shorthand for the current directory.
root_dir = '.'

# What type(s) of files are we looking for?
# prefix = 'image_'
ext_1 = '.jpg'
ext_2 = '.png'

# --- Lists ---

included_files = []
skipped_files = []
directories = []

# A list of every item (files and subdiretories/folders) in our "root_dir".
everything = os.listdir(root_dir)

# natsorted() returns a natural sort rather than a lexographical sort (which
# is what Windows returns by default). So we get e.g. "file_1.ext, file_2.ext,
# file_11.ext, file_22.ext" rather than "file_1.ext, file_11.ext, file_2.ext,
# file_22.ext".
everything_sorted = natsorted(everything)

# --- Functions ---

# Determine the number of zeros to place in front of a new file name.
# "files_count" is the total number of "included_files" we are working with.

def find_padding(item_count, files_count):

    # Holds our final set of zeros as a string.
    temp_padding = ''

    # Find the number to use as the basis for our maximum number of sequence
    # digits. "-1" prevents leading zeros from being added incorrectly to
    # sequences (e.g. 1-100 becomes 00-99 rather than 000-099).
    total_files = files_count - 1

    # Convert "item_count" and "total_files" to strings and count their digits.
    temp_item_digits = len(str(item_count))
    temp_total_digits = len(str(total_files))

    # How many leading zeros do we need?
    if files_count <= 10:
        temp_padding_digits = 1
    else:
        # Total padding = total digits - current digits
        temp_padding_digits = temp_total_digits - temp_item_digits

    # Add the appropriate number of zeros to our "temp_padding" string
    for zeros in range(temp_padding_digits):
        temp_padding += '0'

    # Return our final padding string
    return temp_padding

# --- Main ---

# Visual aid
print('')

# Separate the items in our "root_dir" directory.
for item in everything_sorted:

    # print(item)
    # time.sleep(0.1)

    temp_item = os.path.join (root_dir, item)

    if os.path.isfile(temp_item):
        # if item.startswith(prefix) and item.endswith(ext):
        if item.endswith(ext_1) or item.endswith(ext_2):
            # print(item)
            included_files.append(item)
            # time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            skipped_files.append(item)
    else:
        directories.append(item)

# How many "included_files" do we have?
number_of_files = len(included_files)

# For each of our "included_files", determine the correct padding for a given
# sequence number ("item_number") and rename the file.
for item_number in range(number_of_files):

    # Blank our padding string
    padding = ''

    # Custom function
    padding = find_padding(item_number, number_of_files)

    # Our original file name
    src = included_files[item_number]

    # Create a new name for our current file
    if src.endswith(ext_1):
        # dst = str(item) + ext_1
        dst = padding + str(item_number) + ext_1

    # Create a new name for our current file
    if src.endswith(ext_2):
        # dst = str(item) + ext_2
        dst = padding + str(item_number) + ext_2

    print('Processing:\t', src)
    print('Renaming:\t', src, 'to', dst)
    print('')

    # time.sleep(0.1)

    if rename is True:
        os.rename(src, dst)
```